# triangulation of 3d mesh into equidistant points

Tags: mesh, triangulation

I've been looking for an algorithm that takes any mesh and triangulates it so that all edges are of equal length.

I have some experience in mesh generation and triangulation, but I don't know of any algorithm that can do this, nor can I find it.

Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is remeshing algorithms, for start with some Google search i found this [paper](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~csilva/courses/cpsc7960/pdf/remeshing.pdf) and i think it might be useful to help understanding remeshing in the first place.
Implementation wise [OpenFlipper](http://www.openflipper.org/) has more than one implementation of remeshing, it is open source and easy to read and learn from.
This is an example of remeshing using OpenFlipper
[image: remshing using OpenFlipper]
As you can see you can choose target edge length then start remeshing process resulting 

[image: remshing using OpenFlipper]

Comment: thank you. you are right that my question is about remeshing rather than triangulation. OpenFlipper's remesher even has an edge-length parameter, so that should answer my question.